# PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer to load spring properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-properties

I want to load spring properties using a specific format, not yaml nor properties.

I wrote a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer, which is working perfectly in the UT but...

When I start the Spring Boot app, my PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer is not used to load the spring properties because it's probably loaded after the spring properties.

I try to add the Order annotation or to make the beans static but it didn't works

```
@Bean
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
MyPropertiesPlaceholderConfigurer myPropertiesPlaceholderConfigurer(String[] myConfigurationFiles) {
    return new MyPropertiesPlaceholderConfigurer(myConfigurationFiles);
}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Don't. Write a `PropertySource` implementation instead and write a specific loader for that.

Comment: Then use an `EnvironmentPostProcessor` to add them to the regular `Environment`.

Comment: It works with the PostProcessor.
I can now use variables in my spring yml:

myservice:
  host: myserver
  port: 8080
  baseURL: https://${myservice.host}:{myservice.port}

Thanks